# Azure Web Role Recycles after being deployed

Tags: java, r, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

My Azure Web Role has R,Java etc configured on it automatically before my actual application starts running. Everything configures perfectly fine and the application is running smoothly. I have had no problem with my web app for 2 weeks and it was working fine in an Azure Web Role. Then one day while I was opening my web app I faced an error related to R-core. On remotely accessing my Azure VM, I found out that my R,Java and R packages were deleted. Going through the event viewer I found out that my Azure VM was restarted 3times.

It is an ASP.NET web app hosted in IIS on an Azure Web Role.

After the whole scenario, could you please direct me about Web Role Recycling. When its working fine for 2 weeks how come it recycles itself and deletes my installations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft periodically upgrades the host OS, guest OS, and guest agent hosting the cloud service.  Your VM will be rebooted during this time (or guest agent restarted).  Cloud services are "stateless", meaning in this case that any prerequisites you have for running your application must be installed via a start-up script.

For more details see:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/09/19/role-instance-restarts-due-to-os-upgrades.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/26/troubleshooting-scenario-2-role-recycling-after-running-fine-for-2-weeks.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx

Comment: Thanks Don, the articles were helpful. I placed all my prerequisites in the start-up script and then re-imaged from azure portal just to test whether everything works fine or not. And as expected everything went well.